# Recreating the following table with the logo

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I had asked this question [here](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=30637) ... but I am also asking it here as well. I want to reproduce the following table with the logo.

[image]

I am not sure how to proceed though. Here is a minimal working example

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, array}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm , a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]

\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{m{0.48\textwidth}}}
\begin{center}
The graphic goes here.

Some more text.


\end{center} &
\begin{center}

Some more text.

\end{center}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

However it is far from what I want ... How can I achieve the above? Must I use something like `multirow` or something?

Comment: You've set tag [`tikz-pgf`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/tikz-pgf/info). And using `tikz` would indeed be a suggestion to reproduce it. The three frames on the right side could be nodes with centered text. The left one could be a combination of nodes or a node that contains not only text but, e.g., a `\parbox` with `\includegraphics` and text. But in your example I cannot see any effort in using TikZ. So what's the reason for using this tag? Do you want to know, how to make the logo with TikZ? This would be a "do it for me" question …

Comment: No, I don't want to make the logo... the logo is a picture. I will place it using `includegraphics` ... I'm interested in the table ... I thought tikz would be a good and flexible idea but I'm interested in other approaches as well.

Comment: You should not accept my answer just yet. There might come much better ones in a few minutes/hours. If there are no better ones within a reasonable period of time, you might accept an answer.

Comment: Ok ! I unaccepted your answer !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `TikZ` solution.

First we draw three right nodes one below the other, all of them with same width but particular height. The right part is a `fit` node (as tall as right nodes) with logo and below text defined in its centered label.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[mybox/.style={draw=orange, line width=1mm, minimum width=4cm, text width=3cm, align=center}]

\node[mybox, minimum height=1cm] (1r) {This is some text};
\node[mybox, minimum height=12mm, below=-\pgflinewidth of 1r] (2r) {Text in \\ two rows};
\node[mybox, minimum height=2cm, below=-\pgflinewidth of 2r] (3r) {Some more text in lower row};

\node[draw=orange, line width=1mm, 
    inner sep=-.5\pgflinewidth, 
    fit={(3r.south west) (1r.north west)}, 
    below left=0 and -\pgflinewidth of 1r.north west, 
    minimum width=4cm, 
    label={[text width=3cm, align=center]center:    
        {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-A}\\ 
            Some more text below the icon}}]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using `multirow` the following does work (note however that this is not the only solution):

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{array,graphicx,multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\bgroup
\arrayrulecolor{orange}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\begin{tabular}[]{|*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.4\linewidth}|}}
  \hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\centering%
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image}
    text text text text text text}}
  & 
    text\\
    \cline{2-2}
  &  text text text text text text text text\\
    \cline{2-2}
  &  text text text
  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem with `multirow` is, that it doesn't know the required height, but guesses it based on the first argument (as 3 normal rows). Therefore using a large logo won't work in this way.

Another approach without `multirow` which does work for large images doesn't create nice vertical spacing in the second column automatically:

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{array,graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\bgroup
\arrayrulecolor{orange}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\begin{tabular}[]{| m{0.4\linewidth} | @{}l@{} |}
  \hline
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
  text text text text text text text text
  &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.4\linewidth}}
    text text text\\
    \hline
    text text text text text text\\
    \hline
    text text text text text text text text text
  \end{tabular}\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Inserting a bit of manual space:

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{array,graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\bgroup
\arrayrulecolor{orange}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1pt}
\begin{tabular}[]{| m{0.4\linewidth} | @{}l@{} |}
  \hline
  \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image}
  text text text text text text text text
  &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.4\linewidth}}
    text text text\\[0.5em]
    \hline
    \noalign{\vspace*{0.5em}}
    text text text text text text\\[0.5em]
    \hline
    \noalign{\vspace*{0.5em}}
    text text text text text text text text text
  \end{tabular}\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\end{document}
```

[image]